# Ubuntu 16.04.1 with kernel 4.12.10-041210-generic intel 8260 bluetooth not working

Tags: 16.04, kernel, bluetooth, intel-wireless, firmware

I'm on a Dell latitude E7270 with latest BIOS (sept 2017), running ubuntu 16.04.1. 
I first upgraded the stock 16.04.1 kernel to the mainline 4.11.7-041107-generic without problem, 
then I upgraded to kernel 4.12.10-041210-generic and Wifi and Bluetooth both stopped working. 
So I installed to the latest firmwares using (don't know exactly what was there before the update).

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.167_all.deb 
(Lecture de la base de données... 1877982 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de linux-firmware_1.167_all.deb ...
Dépaquetage de linux-firmware (1.167) sur (1.167) ...
Paramétrage de linux-firmware (1.167) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.12.10-041210-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.11.7-041107-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-93-generic
```

from http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/.

After a reboot Wifi started working again but bluetooth is still down:

```
uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
Linux mypc 4.12.10-041210-generic #201708300614 SMP Wed Aug 30 10:16:40 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I219-LM [8086:156f] (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Ethernet Connection I219-LM [1028:06db]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0050]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:61b6 Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:5805 Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5686 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    3.753864] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.753874] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.753876] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.753878] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.753881] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.761490] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.761491] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.761491] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.761500] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.761501] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.761501] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.761522] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.761533] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    3.761534] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.761534] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.761535] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    4.684487] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.684489] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.684491] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    5.008318] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[    5.015600] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[    5.015602] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    5.015602] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    5.015603] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    5.015604] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    5.015605] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    5.017591] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    5.168505] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
[    7.172835] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    7.172836] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[    0.342425] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.657608] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (v1.26)
[    3.854841] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-30.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.854929] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-29.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.854941] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-28.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.861080] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 27.455470.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.015605] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    5.017591] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[    5.168505] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to send firmware data (-38)
bluetooth             540672  14 btrtl,hci_uart,btintel,btqca,bnep,btbcm,btusb
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
```

So it seems the intel/ibt-11-5.sfi is the culprit but I cannot find any newer intel bluetooth firmware.

Any idea ?

EDIT:

After a clean boot, running this in a terminal fixes bluetooth:

```
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

this gets appended to dmesg:

```
[  527.599582] usbcore: deregistering interface driver btusb
[  542.659674] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[  542.660139] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 2 week 52 2014
[  542.665299] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 5
[  542.665300] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[  542.665301] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[  542.665301] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[  542.665302] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[  542.665303] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[  542.665455] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-11-5.sfi
[  544.470541] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[  544.471154] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1769079 usecs
[  544.471255] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[  544.482452] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 10961 usecs
[  544.482545] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-11-5.ddc
[  544.486308] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[  544.548301] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  544.548312] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  544.548322] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

However I need to modprobe manually after each reboot.
Any idea how to fix this to get it working right after boot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `btusb` to `/etc/modules`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modules
```

this will cause `btusb` to load at boot time.

Comment: OK Just did ! thx